# Better way to do parallelising KafkaStream Processing?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

below is snippet of my code. I want to parallelise kafka stream processing. but i dont want to put into Runnable and i also don't want to start this application multiple times.

Is there any way like streams.parallel()?

```
            final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        Consumed<String, String> types = Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde);
        //create StreamFactory
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        //read message from topic
        KStream<String, String> xmlMessages = builder.stream("from_topic", types);

        //select matched messages
        KStream<String, String> matchedMessages = xmlMessages.filter((key, xmlMessageValue) -> {
          //here does the filter tasks 
        });

        //dispatch matched message to destination topic
        matchedMessages.to("to_topic");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Comment: Running multiple instances of the same application is how you would typically scale this, not threads within one JVM. Otherwise, one JVM dies, the whole thing stops rather than rebalances to other instances

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Streams with multiple threads by setting `num.stream.threads` to a value larger than the default of 1.

The multi-threading will be handled by Kafka internally, there is no need to change application code (to start additional streams or runnables).

But note that

- you cannot make use of more threads than you have partitions in the topic they consume from. The way work is divided between the multiple threads is exactly the same as if you started multiple instances of the Stream (i.e. topic partitions are assigned equally amongst them).
- having multiple threads in the same JVM (as opposed to starting multiple JVM with the same code) does not give you fail-over/rebalance capabilities (all these threads will most likely live and die together).